# How to fill out a web form via selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

There's a website: https://www.nealthy.com/alpha (not advertising), and it has a form for entering name and mail. That would be fine, but this form is something dynamic, because when I try to search for an item to enter the name/email:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="firstname"]')
```

gives an error stating that the element is not found:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="firstname"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.180)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
  (No symbol) [0x00E737D3]
  (No symbol) [0x00E08B81]
  (No symbol) [0x00D0B36D]
  (No symbol) [0x00D3D382]
  (No symbol) [0x00D3D4BB]
  (No symbol) [0x00D73302]
  (No symbol) [0x00D5B464]
  (No symbol) [0x00D71215]
  (No symbol) [0x00D5B216]
  (No symbol) [0x00D30D97]
  (No symbol) [0x00D3253D]
  GetHandleVerifier [0x010EABF2+2510930]
  GetHandleVerifier [0x01118EC1+2700065]
  GetHandleVerifier [0x0111C86C+2714828]
  GetHandleVerifier [0x00F23480+645344]
  (No symbol) [0x00E10FD2]
  (No symbol) [0x00E16C68]
  (No symbol) [0x00E16D4B]
  (No symbol) [0x00E20D6B]
  BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76027D69+25]
  RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77AEBB9B+107]
  RtlClearBits [0x77AEBB1F+191]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to solve the problem with `time.sleep()` , but no matter how many times I set the sleep time, it didn't help.

full code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


ua = UserAgent()
url = "https://www.nealthy.com/alpha"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={ua.chrome}')

web_driver = Service('C:\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe')  #ПУТЬ К ВЕБ ДРАЙВЕРУ
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=web_driver, options=options)

driver.get(url=url)
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="firstname"]').send_keys('Axcent')
```

I tried finding the field element for the name and inserting the name there. I got an error that the element was not found

Answer (score 0):

This website is a bit tricky, they have the form in a shadow Dom.

To access the elements within this DOM, you will need to first find the element hosting it (in this case the form-widget), then run a script to extract the shadow Dom. After that you will be able to access the elements.

Here is the final code to access the email field for example:

```
shadowParent = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'form-widget')
shadowRoot = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", shadowParent)
shadowRoot.find_element(By.ID,'email').send_keys('Axcent')
```

For more information on Shadow Doms:

- https://medium.com/@titus_on_testing/shadow-dom-in-python-selenium-df8d731b5005
- https://reflect.run/articles/testing-shadow-dom-elements-in-selenium/

There is a also a pypi package that claims to simplify this:

- https://pypi.org/project/pyshadow/